# Read from a file OR a file descriptor

Tags: c, file-io, file-descriptor, process-substitution

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<assert.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* input_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    printf("%ld\n", ftell(input_file));
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("%ld\n", ftell(input_file));
    size_t length  = ftell(input_file);
    char* src   = malloc(length);
    assert(src != NULL);
    fseek(input_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(src, 1, length, input_file);
    fclose(input_file);

    // Do stuff with src
    free(src);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out somefile.txt 
0
4
$ ./a.out <(cat somefile.txt)
-1
-1
a.out: a.c:12: main: Assertion `src != ((void *)0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Is there a way to make it work even if the file is a file descriptor obtained by bash process substitution?

Comment: Suggestion: check for `argc > n` before using `argv[n]`

Comment: True - in one case You have file name in `argv` in other You have the contents of the file in standard input

Comment: No, the second call doesn't have to (and can't) read the `cat` command's output from its stdin. `<()` will make bash will generate a FIFO at `/dev/fd/somenumber` that is supposed to be opened and read from like a file. However, because it's not a regular file, you can't use `fseek`, `ftell` etc. on it, and that is the problem here -- you'll not be able to know the length of the "file" in advance and have to rewrite your program accordingly.

Comment: Add: If you inspect `errno` after the `ftell` and `fseek` calls, you'll probably get `ESPIPE`. (remember to reset `errno = 0;` before the calls so that its value is meaningful afterwards)